# Cassandra store long tokens in text or blob?

Tags: cassandra

I will have a user table which will contain a token for each user. The tokens are 1024 bit long alphanumeric strings.  Inside of one of my textbooks they seem to store all tokens inside of blobs instead of text, but never explained why? Is there an advantage to choosing a blob over a text in Cassandra. Is there any performances differences (say for a table with over a billion rows)?

Answer (score 1):

Storing the token as a blob will be more efficient since the blob will be smaller than the text representation.  This means it will use less disk space, be faster to read and write, and be transferred more efficiently over the network.  Smaller data is almost always faster for Cassandra to work with.

The text will usually compress more than the blob, so that will mitigate some of the difference, but the blob will probably still be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think blob and text weight about the same, only blob is not human redable. 
There can be an  improvement in performance if you first gzip the token and then send the gzip as blob as it would be significantly smaller. 
See this [What are the pros or cons of storing json as text vs blob in cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339150/what-are-the-pros-or-cons-of-storing-json-as-text-vs-blob-in-cassandra)